# Swift NSXElement addChild unable to add sub child to child

Tags: xml, swift, nsxmlelement

I am in the process of learning Swift and want to create a xml file based on user input.  I am able to create the document root and one child level but not sub child.  I don't know what I am missing. And How do I "pretty print" to my xml?

Example of desired xml file output:

```
<find_sites>
  <name>Many Sites</name>
       <sites>8</sites>
         <site_info>
              <site_name>First Site</site_name>
              <site_description>Description of first site</site_description>
         </site_info>
</find_sites>
```

My Swift Code in playground:

```
let root = NSXMLElement(name: "find_sites")
let xmlFile = NSXMLDocument (rootElement: root)
root.addChild(NSXMLElement(name: "name", stringValue: "Many Sites"))
root.addChild(NSXMLElement(name: "sites", stringValue: "8"))
let site_info = NSXMLElement(name: "site_info")
root.addChild(NSXMLElement(name: "site_info"))
site_info.addChild(NSXMLElement(name: "site_name", stringValue: "First Site"))
site_info.addChild(NSXMLElement(name: "site_description", stringValue: "Description"))
println(" \(xmlFile.XMLString)")

Results:  <find_sites><name>Many Sites</name><sites>8</sites><site_info></site_info></find_sites>
```

My child elements of 'site_info' are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a new `NSXMLElement` instance as a child of `root` rather than `site_info`. Change line 6 to this:

```
root.addChild(site_info)
```